# how to get current visible android.support.v4.app.Fragment in robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I am using robotium 3.6 and I want to get the current visible fragment of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are actually using the FragmentActivity, then solo.getCurrentActivity() should return the activity you want but it will be casted to an activity, you will need to cast it to an android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity in the normal java way:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = (android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) solo.getCurrentActivity();
```

This may not work if you have this inside a tabhost or such though.